# grub2 is booting from the wrong drive after cloning

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 on an HDD. Recently I bought an SSD. I cloned all the necessary partitions from the HDD to the SSD. I want to put the OS on the SSD and use my HDD for data storage.

When only the SSD is physically connected:

- The SSD is recognized as *sda*.
- Everything works fine, and I can boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 from the SSD after selecting the corresponding GRUB menu entries.

When the HDD and the SSD are both physically connected:

- GRUB is started on the SSD (the SSD is selected in the UEFI BIOS settings)
- The HDD is now *sda* and the SSD is now *sdb*
- The Ubuntu and Windows 10 GRUB menu entries still point to *sda* instead of *sdb* and both operating systems are started from the HDD instead of the SSD.

How can I get GRUB to point to *sdb* instead of *sda*?

This is my Boot-Repair report:

http://paste2.org/pMchfYzj

Comment: By cloning the whole drive you also cloned the EFI partition so now both drives can boot independently. You need to set the drive you want to boot from as the default option in UEFI settings.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I already changed the drive in the UEFI BIOS settings. I can either select the SSD or the HDD. Both settings work, however both lead to the same behavior: The OS is started from the HDD (sda). Seems like GRUB is now on both drives, but both GRUBs point to sda and therefore the OS on the SDD (sdb) is never started.How to change that is the question.

Comment: I recently experienced the same problem. Still studying GRUB2 configuration and customization through command line, but this graphical tool helps in case anybody stumbles upon this: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer